# MemoryCache with Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memorycache

Right now, I am using `MemoryCache` from `System.Runtime.Caching`. Recently, I came to know that `Asp.net Core` framework supports `MemoryCache` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`. As I am using that new framework, I am trying to replace the old library with a new one.

While setting `MemoryCache` It is using `Set Of` property. As I created generic method, I am trying it use it as `Set(Of Object)` but it is throwing an error `Specified Cast is not valid`
Can someone please help me to sort out this issue? Is it better to upgrade it or whichever I am using `System.Runtime.Caching` is fine?
I am using below code:

```
public object GetValue(string key)
  {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    return memoryCache.Get(key);
  }

  public bool Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset absExpiration)
  {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    return memoryCache.Add(key, value, absExpiration);
  }

  public void Delete(string key)
  {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    if (memoryCache.Contains(key))
    {
       memoryCache.Remove(key);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, there is no `MemoryCache.Default` in .net core, why don't you use dependency injection to get an instance of `IMemoryCache` in your class?

Comment: @Soren If I use dependency injection then I need to update the things at many places. Is there any another better solution?

Comment: yes It's possible `new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());` but I didn't use this style of initialization,  and don't know how it works.

Comment: @Soren Ohkk. Is it fine if I keep as it is whatever I am currently using?

Comment: the method (names) in dotnet core are completely different,  you can use `cache.Set()` and `cache.Remove()` instead of old ones, or even use advance method like `cache.GetOrCreate()`. but functionality are the same ;)